# PHP not support double

Tags: java, php

I have written one function which is giving diff out put in PHP and Java. Please help me to get same output in PHP too. below are that functions written in both languages.

Function in Java:

```
public String getLat(String v_str, String strNS){
   try
   {            
       double lat = Integer.parseInt(v_str.substring(0, 2));
       //System.out.println("lat="+lat);
       double lat2 = Float.parseFloat(v_str.substring(2));
       lat2 = lat2*10000;
       lat2 = lat2/60*10000;
       lat2 = lat2/100000000;
       //System.out.println("lat2="+lat2);
       lat += lat2;

       if(strNS.equals("S"))
            return ("-"+lat);
       else
            return (""+lat);
   }
   catch(Exception e){}

   return ("");
}
```

Call: `getLat("5224.09960","N");`

Output: `52.40165999730428`

Function in PHP:

```
$deg_coord = '5224.09960';

$lat = (int)(substr($deg_coord,0,2));
$lat2 = (substr($deg_coord,2));

$lat2 = $lat2*10000;
$lat2 = $lat2/60*10000;
$lat2 = $lat2/100000000;
echo $lat += $lat2;
exit;
```

Output: `52.40166`

Comment: use `Double.parseDouble(str)` instead of `double lat = Integer.parseInt("11.4");
        double lat2 = Float.parseFloat("11.2");`

Comment: I want same output in PHP man..

Comment: Try `printf("%.16f", $lat)` instead of `echo`...

Comment: @Jimit, the output in PHP looks more correct.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth, Then I am getting '52.4016599999999997' but not same as '52.40165999730428'

Comment: @Jimit, The idfference is that both answers have a different rounding error. The correct answer is 52.40166.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your Java answer is incorrect due to a rounding error. This could be because you use Float instead of Double as float's precision is much more limited than double.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getLat("5224.09960","N"));
}

public static double getLat(String v_str, String strNS) {
    double lat = Integer.parseInt(v_str.substring(0, 2));
    double lat2 = Double.parseDouble(v_str.substring(2));
    lat += lat2 / 60;
    return strNS.equals("S") ? -lat : lat;
}
```

prints

```
52.40166
```

I suspect using string manipulation is unsafe as latitudes start at 0. i.e. it only happens to work for numbers with 4 digits in front of the decimal point.

This code makes no assumptions about the number of digits. (It does assume you want to round to 6 decimal places)

```
public static double getLat(String v_str, String strNS) {
    double v = Double.parseDouble(v_str);
    double lat = ((long) v)/100;
    double lat2 = (v - lat * 100) / 60;
    double lat3 = lat + lat2;
    double rounded = (double)(long) (lat3 * 1000000 + 0.5) / 1000000;
    return strNS.equals("S") ? -rounded : rounded;
}
```

---

If you want to reproduce the same rounding error in PHP, you could try

```
$deg_coord = '5224.09960';

$lat = (int)(substr($deg_coord,0,2));
$lat2 = (float) (substr($deg_coord,2));

$lat2 = $lat2*10000;
$lat2 = $lat2/60*10000;
$lat2 = $lat2/100000000;
echo $lat += $lat2;
exit;
```

Comment: No, I want output same as JAVA in PHP

Comment: You want to reproduce the same rounding error? That is mad. However, see my edit. BTW as I have noted, about half your code doesn't do anything and wouldn't work for latitudes less than 1000.